# check the first character of string and replace it by jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to check the first character of the string, if it is `equal to 5`, then replace it by `"five"`. I am using the following code, but it can only check the whole string, not the first character. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var str="div.productView-description-tabContent";
       $(document).ready( function() {
             $("div.productView-description-tabContent:contains('5')").html("five");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps you.

> Also an example provided that you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/nak73406/yzb5x38u/14/

Simple HTML code

```
    <div class="productView-description-tabContent">
          5 Labore irure do esse ullamco est sit qui ut duis magna voluptate mollit in laboris non aliquip in.
    </div>
```

Jquery Code

```
     var str= jQuery('div.productView-description-tabContent').html();
     var firstChar = str.charAt(0); // Get the first char 
     if(firstChar == '5' || firstChar == 5 ){ // check that the first char is 5 or not
     // if it was 5 then replace it with 'Five'          
     $("div.productView-description-tabContent").text(function () {
          return $(this).text().replace("5", "Five"); 
      });
     }
```

Out Put

> Five Labore irure do esse ullamco est sit qui ut duis magna voluptate mollit in laboris non aliquip in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to replace `^5` (in English: the start of the string, followed by the character 5) with `'five'`:

```
const productView = document.querySelector("div.productView-description-tabContent");
productView.innerHTML = productView.innerHTML.replace(/^5/, 'five');
```

If there are more than one such elements, then iterate over them instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.productView-description-tabContent").forEach((productView) => {
  productView.innerHTML = productView.innerHTML.replace(/^5/, 'five');
});
```